# How to load a page into a div after using header

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I would like to know how do I load a html page into a div, after using the header into a php code.

For example:

I have the main page. When I click the menu on the left side, it loads a page inside the div named "content".
Inside the div named content, I have a form, after filling the form, I click the "Send" button.

By clicking the send button, I get redirected to my php code, which is **insert_produto.php**

Inside the page **insert_produto.php** I have the following code:

```html
<?php

include '../logado.php';

$tipo =$_POST["tipo"];
$marca =$_POST["marca"];
$comprimento =$_POST["comprimento"];
$externo =$_POST["externo"];
$interno =$_POST["interno"];

$quantidade =$_POST["quantidade"];

//$conen tem que ser o nome da conexão, depois disso monta a query

//mysqli_query($conec,"INSERT INTO produtos (tipo) VALUES ('$tipo')");

if ($quantidade == "") {
 $quantidade = 1;
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= $quantidade; $i++) {

  if ($externo == '' or $interno == '') {
    echo "Os seguintes valores são obrigatórios:</p>";
    echo "• Diâmetro Externo;</p>";
    echo "• Diâmetro Interno.";
    echo "</br></br>";

    echo '<form id="erro" action="../main.php" method="post">';

    echo '<input type="submit" class="botao" value="Voltar">';

    echo '</form>';

    die;
}

// se INTEIRO = primeira query, ELSE segunda query
if ($comprimento == '' and $tipo == 'Inteiro'){

mysqli_query($conec,"INSERT INTO produtos (tipo, marca, comprimento, diaexterno, diainterno) VALUES ('$tipo', '$marca', '1000', '$externo', '$interno')");

} elseif ($comprimento == '' and $tipo == 'Pedaço') {

echo "Os seguintes valores são obrigatórios:</p>";
echo "• Comprimento;</p>";
echo "</br></br>";
echo '<form id="erro" action="../main.php" method="post">';
echo '<input type="submit" class="botao" value="Voltar">';
echo '</form>';
die;

} else {

mysqli_query($conec,"INSERT INTO produtos (tipo, marca, comprimento, diaexterno, diainterno) VALUES ('$tipo', '$marca', '$comprimento', '$externo', '$interno')");

}

} // ENCERRA O LAÇO DE REPETIÇÃO "FOR"

//header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
header("location: /main.php");

echo '<div class="content">
    <?php include("/cadastro/produto.php"); ?>
</div>
'

?>
```

After the *FOR*, I use Header to return to the main page. However, when I get to the main page, I would like to reload the previous html page inside the div called "content".

I don't mind too if I have to specify manually which page I want to load inside the div, I actually prefer this way.

Comment: Hi Kouhei, you can use jQuery/Ajax to send the request once the user clicks Send and depending on the response you can change the content of any div using jQuery.
PHP cannot access DOM contents and will not be able to help you in making changes to any div.

Comment: Your last echo after your header wont be executed, because it loads `/main.php` Edit `/main.php` so it includes `/cadastro/produto.php`

Comment: thanks for the replies, im trying to find a work-around

so far i've tried to instead of going to the php page, just executing its content without leaving the currently page, but no success at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure how to solve this issue, so i made an work-around

i'll explain how i made that work-around, so anyone facing the same issue may find it helpful

First, at the end of the php code, i simple added the following line:
$_SESSION["pagina"] ="cadastro_produto";

before the: header("location: /main.php");

then, at my main.php i did this:
$teste =$_SESSION["pagina"];

and inside the div "content", i made this

```html
<?php

if ($teste == 'cadastro_produto'){

echo '<div id="caixa">
Cadastrado com sucesso.</p>
voltar
</div>';

//header("location: /cadastro/produto.php")

}

$_SESSION["pagina"] = "";

?>
```

i put $_SESSION["pagina"] = ""; at end, so i can set the variable teste to blank, this way an refresh of the page would not make this appear again

i know this isnt the best way to fix the problem, but it worked for me and its enough for what i need

plus i would need to figure out how to make a return message if the "insert into" was successful or not, that way i can make the return msg and echo a back button to the form

this solution solves my problem, but i thank everyone who tried to help

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you're using *Location* header, which change the HTTP result code to **302 Redirect**, with the content you echoed after (in this case, the <div> and include of */cadastro/produto.php*. All modern browsers will ignore the content received and will redirect user to *Location* URL.
The only way to do what you want is to submit the form using AJAX and process the response.

For example, you could do it like this (using jQuery), considering you have *id=form* at your <form> tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#form').on ( 'submit', function ( e)
{
  e && e.preventDefault;
  $.ajax (
  {
    url: 'insert_produto.php',
    error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      alert ( 'Error sending form: ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText);
    },
    success: function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
      if ( typeof ( data) == 'object' && 'result' in data)
      {
        if ( data.result == 'ok')
        {
          alert ( 'Added!');
          $('#content').load ( data.location);
        } else {
          alert ( data.message);
        }
      } else {
        alert ( 'Unknown data received.');
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

At your PHP script, you'll need to return a JSON object with the structure:

```
{
  "result": "ok",
  "location": "\/cadastro\/produto.php"
}
```

And on error, with the structure:

```
{
  "result": "error",
  "message": "My error message"
}
```

You could do it using:

```html
<?php

include '../logado.php';

$tipo =$_POST["tipo"];
$marca =$_POST["marca"];
$comprimento =$_POST["comprimento"];
$externo =$_POST["externo"];
$interno =$_POST["interno"];

$quantidade =$_POST["quantidade"];

$return = array ();
header ( "Content-Type: text/json");

//$conen tem que ser o nome da conexão, depois disso monta a query

//mysqli_query($conec,"INSERT INTO produtos (tipo) VALUES ('$tipo')");

if ($quantidade == "") {
 $quantidade = 1;
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= $quantidade; $i++) {

if ($externo == '' or $interno == ''){
  $return["result"] = "error";
  $return["message"] = "Os seguintes valores são obrigatórios:\n• Diâmetro Externo;\nDiâmetro Interno.";
  die ( json_encode ( $return);
}

// se INTEIRO = primeira query, ELSE segunda query
if ($comprimento == '' and $tipo == 'Inteiro'){

mysqli_query($conec,"INSERT INTO produtos (tipo, marca, comprimento, diaexterno, diainterno) VALUES ('$tipo', '$marca', '1000', '$externo', '$interno')");

} elseif ($comprimento == '' and $tipo == 'Pedaço') {

  $return["result"] = "error";
  $return["message"] = "Os seguintes valores são obrigatórios:\n• Comprimento.";
  die ( json_encode ( $return);

} else {

mysqli_query($conec,"INSERT INTO produtos (tipo, marca, comprimento, diaexterno, diainterno) VALUES ('$tipo', '$marca', '$comprimento', '$externo', '$interno')");

}

} // ENCERRA O LAÇO DE REPETIÇÃO "FOR"

$return["result"] = "ok";
$return["location"] = "/cadastro/produto.php";
die ( json_encode ( $return);
?>
```

Comment: i tried this, but unfortunately i couldnt understand how does it works, nor could i make it work :/ but thanks anyway

Comment: It works intercepting the form submit at page, send it using AJAX and process the response with *alert()* popup when has an error or loading the URI indicated at div if successfully.